# Find the derivative of an integral with respect to the upper limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f(t,y): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function of two variables and let $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function of one variable. Fix $a\in\mathbb R$.
Compute $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^t f(s,\phi(s))\,ds$$ in terms of $f$ and $\phi$.

I've been used to solving with numbers but weak in theory. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: This is not really an ODE question.  Just define $g(t) = \int_a^t f(s, ∅(s))ds$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute $g'(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea given in the comments. Since $f$ is a continuous real valued function, then you can use the F.T.C. to get $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^t f(s,\phi(s))ds=f(t,\phi(t)), \forall t>a$$